# Is there a "findmnt" equivalent for OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, software-recommendation, unix

I find `findmnt`'s output much easier for a quick scan of the filesystem status than the traditional `mount` command.

Here is a sample output, showing the details it offers.

```
$ findmnt
TARGET                       SOURCE                       FSTYPE     OPTIONS
/                            /dev/disk/by-uuid/b70...92ec ext4       rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered
|-/sys                       sysfs                        sysfs      rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
| |-/sys/fs/fuse/connections                              fusectl    rw,relatime
| |-/sys/kernel/debug                                     debugfs    rw,relatime
| `-/sys/kernel/security                                  securityfs rw,relatime
|-/proc                      proc                         proc       rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
|-/dev                       udev                         devtmpfs   rw,relatime,size=2015976k,nr_inodes=503994,mode=755
| `-/dev/pts                 devpts                       devpts     rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000
`-/run                       tmpfs                        tmpfs      rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=404956k,mode=755
  |-/run/lock                                             tmpfs      rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k
  `-/run/shm                                              tmpfs      rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime
```

- It's part of [util-linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux) package.
- [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh/) package explicitly [did not include this (and dozens of other) tool(s)](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/util-linux)

Is there an equivalent for it on macOS?

Comment: There might be ways to simulate/generate the output you are looking for. As most OSX users aren't familiar with `findmnt`, can you add some sample output to the question?

Comment: Does OSX have any of the subdirectories? If not then what does this command add?

Comment: @Mark it's not about the specific sub-directories but about having a more readable output than plain `mount`. e.g. when my backup disk is connected or a remote SMB volume is mounted, both under `/Volumes`, I find it easier to find them with output like `findmnt` than plain `mount`.

Comment: This sure would be useful to reimplement for APFS snapshots …. Super presentation of relevant details in an easy to scan format.

Comment: Brew says: `The following tools are not supported for macOS, and are therefore not included:` I believe macOS explicit those packages but not 100% sure